# General Errors with ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am new to stackoverflow and am needing help.

Last night I was working on an ASP.NET webpage using C# [I'm all very new to it] and after losing a lot of my progress after a flash drive failure, I had to rewrite from a backup I stored on google drive. After putting it onto my computer, I received problems with one of my webpages. At first it did not recognize objects "existing in the current context" but I rewrote the page from hand, because I thought it was some trouble caused by copy-pasting things back. Now I get these errors:

1. Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends t he correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
2. 'ASP.index_aspx.GetTypeHashCode();: no suitable method found to override
3. 'ASP.index_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)': no suitable method found to override
4. 'ASP.index_aspx' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable'

I did not have these problems at all when working with the version that I lost. Here is my code:

This is my "upload.aspx" page

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="upload" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
     <title>BSHUpload</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- Menu -->
 <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-selected"><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="requests.aspx">Requests</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
<!-- Server-side Upload -->
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="padding-left: 2em">
    <div>
    <h1>Upload a File</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus1" runat="server" Text="---"></asp:Label>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fdFileDrop1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnFileDrop1" runat="server" Text="upload" OnClick="btnFileDrop1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnFileDrop1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSavePath1 = "C:\\UploadBin\\";

    if (fdFileDrop1.HasFile)
    {

        string strFileName = fdFileDrop1.FileName;

            strSavePath1 += strFileName;
            fdFileDrop1.SaveAs(strSavePath1);

            lblStatus1.Text = "Your file was saved as " + strFileName;

    }
    else
    {
        lblStatus1.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload";
    }
}
 }
```

And because I think the bottom 3 errors are for the "index.aspx" page here is that also:

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>BSHUpload</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height: 228px">
<!-- Menu -->
    <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-selected"><a href="upload.aspx">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="requests.aspx">Requests</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="padding-left: 2em">

    </form>
<div>
    <button id="button1">Testing</button>
        <p id="toggle1">
        Wala
        </p>
    <script>
        $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
            $( "#toggle1" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
        })
    </script>
</div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Code Behind for index.aspx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class index: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I really hope you guys can help because I'm stumped here. I'm pretty sure that both the inherits and the "System.Web.UI.Page" is correct but it says it is not.

Comment: Do you have a `index_aspx`? The problem seems to be with that page and not with `upload` according the error description you pasted.

Comment: Yup just noticed that, I put it in the question just now. It says the first one is in "upload.aspx.cs" but then the bottom there are IN App_Web_4sfvqml1.4.cs and it mentions index_aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on `index.aspx`. Check this at the very top of the file

```
CodeFile="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="index"
```

That's wrong. You're pointing to the incorrect code file. It should be

```
CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index"
```